# How to compare two records of 2 separate tables in the same schema and show only the difference in Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle

I have a source table and a target table in the same schema.  Based on the primary key value , I would want to compare the records of the source and destination tables and show only the columns which are having different values.

Could you please help me out on how to get a solution for the same ?

Note : DB version I am having : Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the two tables have the same columns (same column names) with the same data type? (And not, for example, a phone number stored as number in one table and as string in the other?) Are the column names known in advance, so they can be hard-coded in the query? Also, what do you mean by "show... the columns" - what does "showing columns" mean? And, are there any unusual data type columns (for example CLOB columns) in the tables? That would make the question much harder, since you can't group by CLOB columns, for example (a common, efficient approach to your question).

Comment: 1. the column names are differing but data type is same
2. the column names are known in advance hence can be hard coded
3. by "showing columns" I meant the query output should dispay the names of the columns(it can be either source table column name or corresponding target table column name) which are having differing values
4. There is no unusual data type like clob,they are restricted to conventional datatypes like varchar and numbers

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use [CONCAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) to concatenate multiple texts into one. Since you have multiple columns, you can view this problem-space as the concatenation of many expressions, one for each column. Your expression for a column could look like:

```
CASE WHEN ((r1.c1 IS NULL) AND (r2.c1 IS NULL)) OR (r1.c1 = r2.c1)
THEN ''
ELSE CONCAT('Table1: ', r1.c1, ', Table2: ', r2.c1, ';')
END
```

Now that we know how the expression looks like for a field, let's assume there are three fields:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
CASE WHEN ((r1.c1 IS NULL) AND (r2.c1 IS NULL)) OR (r1.c1 = r2.c1)
THEN ''
ELSE CONCAT('Table1: ', r1.c1, ', Table2: ', r2.c1, ';')
END,
CASE WHEN ((r1.c2 IS NULL) AND (r2.c2 IS NULL)) OR (r1.c2 = r2.c2)
THEN ''
ELSE CONCAT('Table1: ', r1.c2, ', Table2: ', r2.c2, ';')
END,
CASE WHEN ((r1.c3 IS NULL) AND (r2.c3 IS NULL)) OR (r1.c3 = r2.c3)
THEN ''
ELSE CONCAT('Table1: ', r1.c3, ', Table2: ', r2.c3, ';')
END) AS diff
FROM table1 r1
JOIN table2 r2
ON r1.id = r2.id;
```

This is the basic idea, but you will encounter some problems, like the types of the fields. If they are not textual, then you will need to convert them into some text. Also, if you need to reuse this diff tool, then you cannot assume that you know the number of fields to compare or even their name, so you will need to load the fields and generate the query based on their names and types.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the solution , there is one further issue in my case , the tables are pretty huge , hence joining the tables will not be feasible , is there an alternate solution to it ?

Comment: @SomnathBose you need to find differences between each two column pairs where difference is present accross two tables sharing the id. The most feasible approach to do this according to general consensus is to do a join. You can do alternatives, like Descartes multiplication with filtering, but that will not yield better results. You are also able to generate files or data structures, but I do not really see why would those improve your solution. If there is slowness in your queries, then you may need to optimize your schema or approach. Doing such diffs for each field for each row pair

Comment: ... is time-consuming, there is no way around that.

Comment: @Lajos: how huge? And what percentage of rows do you expect to be different? I do a similar comparison on two tables with 20+ mio rows every night in production. However, I only display that the rows are different, and don't detail which column it was. But that that could be added...

Comment: @wolφi that largely depends on the data and the schema, so such metrics should be measured in a case-by-case basis. However, if you have a large dataset, then it makes sense to artificially filter out unchanged values. You could create a last_change timestamp that would be actualized by a trigger upon each insertion/update and then you could filter your results in your periodical task so that you would ignore rows whose last_change is older than the last run. If you have 20 million rows, but only 10000 changed during the day, that would make quite a different in performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar job which compares two large tables (26 mio rows each). I don't need to know which column is different, but if I rephrase the query to do that, it would be something along the lines of

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id  NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  a   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  b   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  c   NUMBER     NULL
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id  NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  x   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  y   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  z   NUMBER     NULL
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, 10, 20, 30);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1, 10, 20, 30);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2, 10, 20, 30);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2, 11, 20, 30);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (3, 10, 21, 30);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (3, 10, 20, 30);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (4, 10, 20, 31);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (4, 10, 20, 30);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (5, 10, 20, null);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (5, 10, 20, 30);


SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN a <> x THEN 1 ELSE 0 END a_x,
       CASE WHEN b <> y THEN 1 ELSE 0 END b_y,
       CASE WHEN c <> z 
              OR (c IS     NULL AND z IS NOT NULL) 
              OR (c IS NOT NULL AND z IS     NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END c_z
  FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING (id)
 WHERE a <> x
    OR b <> y
    OR c <> z OR (c IS     NULL AND z IS NOT NULL) 
              OR (c IS NOT NULL AND z IS     NULL);

ID  A_X  B_Y  C_Z
 2    1    0    0
 3    0    1    0
 4    0    0    1
 5    0    0    1
```

The code is lengthy, but I got a script that looks at the data dictionary and writes the query.

However, I'm not totally happy with the comparison of the nullable columns. There is a undokumented system function that makes that easier, but I never got it properly working...